# How do you test reports and analytic engines like BI/BW?

Tags: regression-testing, functional

I'm working with several companies that are deploying [SAP HANA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAP_HANA) (in memory appliance that compresses data from the DB and moves the entire structure into memory resulting in query times that are ~3600 times faster). Our problem is we need to functionally test the system to ensure the right data arrived, no corruption occurred, the apps were modified to talk to this appliance rather than the DB correctly, etc.

We came up with a basic way to do this but we need more.  We're going to run some reports with the system before migrating to HANA and then run the reports afterwards. They should be the same since the application shouldn't have changed functionally and the data should be identical even though it's in columnar format and in a different location.

How else can you functionally test reports or reporting UIs like BI or BW?  What about Flash or CRM apps?

Also, I'd like to find a way to automate this.  If anyone has experience automating BOBJ, let me know.  I'd love to buy you a steak dinner.

Comment: This might be useful, a question about testing backend migrations: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/how-to-test-data-migration-procedure/2633

Comment: Mike, when you say the same, what do you mean? The same content, the same layout, the same user interaction? Each can be tested differently.

Comment: Check out diffkit.org, its a command line Java tool that will diff entire DBs.  With it you can easily setup automated tests for larg edata structures.

Answer (score 1):

No steak dinner for me and a bit of a general reply but do you have a way in your apps to capture the query/results going to/from the database? We have done a similar thing with SQL Server Analysis Services and then written an application to "replay" the traces and verify the response. Once you have the queries and results in text format (assume that's what the traces show) you can write scripts to vary the queries to test other functionality beyond the original queries.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this useful:

Testing SAP HANA
http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/609decf2-9963-2f10-c5ae-9812c8191a33?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&54395760816167

There is a section regarding automation that may be relevant for the OP:

Page 8 section 3.2.2 Automation of Test Cases, state:
"After having designed test cases for SAP HANA, user clients and application servers as well as at
least having executed them once successfully, the test cases are ready to be automated for
regression test purposes.
In order to do so, SAP recommends to use SAP Quick Test Professional by HP for the following
reasons:
x Quick Test Professional is the state of the art test automation tool
x Quick Test Professional supports nearly all user clients and application servers
x Quick Test Professional is part of SAP Testing Options 1 & 2 and therefore integrates with
SAP Solution Manager and SAP Quality Center by HP
x Quick Test Professional is already licensed at many SAP customers
x Quick Test Professional is an easy to use record & replay test automation tool
The test automation approach using SAP Quick Test Professional by HP is similar to standard test
automation approaches for ERP-Systems. This means from a customer perspective: there is
already a high degree of test automation knowledge available, which can easily be reused for test
automation of SAP HANA, user clients and application servers. "

However there could be other ways of driving the reporting tools and making assertions based on a known data set you are processing. HP QC might not be the only option. If the reports you are re-running are web based/flash based then perhaps Selemium or Watir is an option and would work fine if you can control the data they expect to assert on. At any rate- you have a lot of options here but most of them will involve the ability for you to control the input of a known data set for SAP HANA to process and then either make assertions at the level of data destination source, available api to consume that data, or client interface from an end user perspective. I don't know how SAP HANA appliance gets it's data to begin with but that is where you need to control the input.

Comment: Can you can explain why this article might be useful? Besides the similarity in title?

Comment: Link-only answers are subject to link rot, and as such, we'd really prefer if you put the information needed into your answer. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers for more details

Answer (score 0):

We just went through the same HANA upgrade in SAP. BW was already on HANA. We chose to test by validating the PSA ( staging) against SAP to ensure all the data came into BW correctly.  Since there were no changes in BW to the other layers ( cubes, reports etc) we didnot test those portions